# Elasticsearch sorting based on several fields and time condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a little online store application and I would like to sort items based on their active price. So there is a normal price and optionally a discounted price. But the discounted price is valid for a time range only and the index is not updated when discount ends. For example:

```
{price: 2.00, discount:{price:1.10, start:2016-08-11, end:2016-09-14}}
```

Is it possible to include such condition on sorting? The goal is to ensure the correct sort order any given time.

Edit: At the moment the ES version is rather old but update to the latest is not an issue.

Comment: You can do this using _script, basically, you will have to write yourself a script with which sort will operate. I cannot help you make the script  request yet, since i've never used _script option yet, so I won't post this as an answer, but you can find more informations here:
 [Script Based Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-request-sort.html)

Comment: You haven't provided much info in the post: what is the mapping of `discount` field, what ES version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Elasticsearch 5 and 6 (you didn't mention, as I said, the version and the mapping of that `discount` field). Also, you need to explicitly pass as a parameter the current date and time in milliseconds whenever you run that query:

```
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "if (doc['discount.price']!=null && doc['discount.start'].date.getMillis() < params['time'] && doc['discount.end'].date.getMillis() > params['time']) return doc['discount.price'].value; else return doc['price'].value",
        "params": {
          "time": 1512717897000
        }
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a note for the OP: In ES 6, it warns: #! Deprecation: getDate is no longer necessary on date fields as the value is now a date.

You may use: `doc['discount.start'].value.getMillis()` instead of `doc['discount.start'].date.getMillis()`.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that @ArchitSaxena. Thank you for adding this comment.